# Conceptually, how do I do a simple Read/Update cycle using LiveData and Room?

Tags: android, kotlin

In a Repository class (see: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide), I'm trying to:

1) Read a value from the Room DB

2) Increment the value

3) Write the value back out through the appDao to Room.

I'm pretty sure I can solve this at the Dao level, ie in a Transaction or something, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach.  It seems like a pretty simple use case, and the solutions I've come up with seem way more complicated than necessary.  I'm wondering if my tenuous handle on Kotlin coroutines is holding me back here.

```
/* Repository Class*/

fun getCurrentAlarmTime():LiveData<Calendar> {
        return Transformations.map(appDao.getProfileData(currentAlarmTime)){ nullableProfileData ->
           if (nullableProfileData == null) {
               defaultAlarmTime
           } else {
               nullableProfileData.value.toLongOrNull()?.let { millis ->
                   getCalendar(millis)
               }
           }
        }
    }

fun setCurrentAlarmTime(calendar:Calendar) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            appDao.setProfileData(
                ProfileData(
                    currentAlarmTime,
                    calendar.timeInMillis.toString()
                )
            )
        }
    }

fun incrementAlarmTimeBy1Hour() {
// this is what I'm having a problem with, using the fns above.
// I've got a pretty good handle on LiveData, 
// Transformations, and MediatorLiveData, 
// but I am still stuck.
}

Expected result would be that the time in the database is updated by 1 hour.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out something that's not a terrible solution, by reading the reference for Room here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data

The crux of it is that Room can return LiveData, or it can return what I would call synchronous queries.  It's the difference between the following two signatures:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM profileData WHERE entry = :entry limit 1")
fun getProfileData(entry: String): LiveData<ProfileData?>

@Query("SELECT * FROM profileData WHERE entry = :entry limit 1")
suspend fun getProfileDataSync(entry: String): ProfileData
```

The first one you would observe, the second one you could call directly from a coroutine.

Someone should let me know if this is not best practice, but it seems like that reference material above supports it.

To note, I didn't have to put the Room DB in any kind of weird synchronous mode to support this.

Comment: I like to call the first variant `getXxxxWithChanges()` and the second as just `getXxxx()`. Suspend isn't really sync, I feel.